# How to debug JavaScript code with mobile browsers

Tags: browser, mobile, firebug

I know about firebug and the developer tools for the major modern desktop browsers, but I can't find any way of debugging JavaScript code on mobile browsers.

What are some high level techniques I can use to debug code on mobile browsers?

Comment: What I do is look at the mobile version in a desktop browser and debug it there.

Comment: @JohnIsaacks Some websites show incorrectly in desktop browser. Our duty is debugging it on real device and fix it for desktop browser.

Comment: Most of the times it's all about the size so there is some online tools like http://responsinator.com that show a page in different phones and tablet sizes, all in one page!  
[Here](http://www.gonzoblog.nl/2012/03/21/10-testing-tools-for-responsive-web-design/) are list of 10 of them.  
As I tested http://responsinator.com works even with your localhost urls.  
Personally these tools answer most of my similar needs for responsive web designing.  
Also it's possible to simulate different agents by [chrome](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html).

Answer (score 3):

Android devices can be put into developer mode by going through settings>Phone status then tapping on "Build number" 7 times. This allows you to do a [bunch of things (see step 5)](http://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-hidden-secret-developer-options-menu-in-google-android-mobiles-phones-and-tablets/) including USB debugging. (Some devices might have Build number under Software Info)

To activate USB debugging, look in Settings for the newly appeared "{ } Developer Options", open this and switch on USB debugging. Connect your device using a direct USB connection.

In Chrome on your desktop, in the usual developer tools panel used for debugging, look in the menu for more tools>remote devices. With Discover USB devices selected, you should now see your mobile device on the side.

Select it to see a list of all the chrome tabs you have open and the ability to enter URLs directly.

Selecting one of the links will open up a new window with a mirror of your device screen on the left and all the familiar chrome debug tools on the right. You can still control your device directly or use the mouse on the mirrored screen. It even rotates.

full details [on remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) from google and  [how to enable developer mode](http://www.askvg.com/tip-enable-hidden-secret-developer-options-menu-in-google-android-mobiles-phones-and-tablets/) (link as above) from askvg.com

Comment: This method is avalable for firefox too. for [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_with_WebIDE)

Answer (score 2):

You can debug on Safari Mobile with any iPhone/iPad. In Developer menu you can find your device and you can then debug your code with inspector.

If you have an Android Device instead, you can debug on Chrome Desktop (remember to active the debug mode) with `chrome://inspect`

Answer (score 2):

Android provides a tool set for these purposes:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Apple does it a similar way:
https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/

Tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/using-chrome-devtools-to-debug-javascript-in-any-browser-with-ghostlab-2/

Answer (score 1):

On the IPhone you can go into settings>Safari>advanced and turn web inspector on

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get bugs reported by customers that are not reproducible every time or in our testing. For such cases I recommend [Lucky Orange](https://www.luckyorange.com). It records the user activity and also has the option to record console messages.

PS - I'm not an affiliate, I use them for my own projects and like it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for basic debugging (which many times is all is needed), is having a console polyfill on mobile without the need to plug into USB on desktop.

[mobileConsole](https://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mobileconsole-javascript-console-for-mobile-devices/) is such a console polyfill.

Hope it helps someone, I found it useful.