# Disable content for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a site that has the following to control the experience:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)" href="styles.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css"/>
```

Essentially, the site is designed like 1996 websites and then the styles are meant to modernize it. Mobile devices should have 1 set of styles, tablets and computers another.

This works great (although, I may need to change 480 to 640 to grab some of the larger smart phones coming out, which I can't test).

The problem I am attempting to solve is the sidebar. There is a small section at the end of the document which displays to the right side of the page, but for mobile, it has `display:none` so it doesn't show. Some of the content there is a random photo thumbnail from the gallery, and advertisement, etc. I want it so this content doesn't download (~200KB), as opposed to just hiding it as I am currently doing. What is the best approach?

Comment: if you want the content (HTML) to not even populate on mobile devices, CSS will not provide this. What you need is some kind of server-side detection of mobile, and only print that HTML when it is not a mobile device.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657159/when-using-media-queries-does-a-phone-load-non-relevent-queries-and-images) may be worth looking at.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea That is what I was afraid of. This is how I used to do it, but that becomes much more complicated, especially as the market gets flooded with more and more devices. Plus, my site really is size dependent. For instance, the full site looks good on a Samsung Note in landscape because of its large size.

Comment: are u using PHP or ASP? because there is a killer PHP script I use for mobile detection (and I've used it for this exact purpose) => https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect. it's very comprehensive, and pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Are the images loaded dynamically from a database or are they just part of the design or flat HTML/CSS content?

If it's the latter the easiest way is to load the images as background images in CSS, rather than using the  tag in the HTML. The downloading of the image is then completely controlled by the media queries you wrote.

Of course this has the adverse effect of removing the  tag from the HTML which may be a problem if the image is important to your SEO etc.

Comment: Just flat HTML, not even with CSS, but I like the idea. Makes the site a little more complicated (especially using a WYSIWYG editor like the other admins do to add content), but would work. I'll look into it. Thanks for the idea

Comment: A good reference for this technique: http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/