# How to stop div from loading on mobile?

Tags: jquery, performance, replacewith

I am looking for away to speed up my mobile site.

One way is to remove the giant fading banner - using css like 'display none' and 'visability hidden' wont stop the images loading on the backend.

From what I can tell anyway. Google speed test also says that the banner is still loading.

I also tried jquery to `replacewith` the content of that div to be empty, which works visually. But the images still seam to load in the code background. Google still reports the same images loading. I guess the div is created for a millisecond then the jquery kicks in?

Comment: Here's a [great article](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/) linked from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668355/854246)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery removes it after DOM is ready, but ready means that the banner image is already loaded/is loading. If you want to remove it, you need rewrite the code a little bit or you can create class for mobile and for desktop and load the image as background in that div, so on mobile you won't load the image and hide div

Comment: Okay thanks, I was hoping it would be easier. Looks like I'll need to re-write the gallery system.