# Are link with unmached media is loaded?

Tags: html, css, optimization, media-queries, retina

I can `<link>` a stylesheet with `media` parameter like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="retina.css" media="(min-resolution: 2dppx)">
```

But if I use images inlined with `data-uri` in `retina.css` the file will be large. I do not want to load this extra megabyte when it's not needed.

So my question is simple: will it load if `media` will not match? (`min-resolution` is less than `2dppx` for this case.)

And if it will be loaded anyway, is there any `js` library to load it only on `media` match?

Comment: possible duplicate [When using @media queries, does a phone load non-relevent queries and images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657159/when-using-media-queries-does-a-phone-load-non-relevent-queries-and-images)

Comment: @lkmhr very similar to my question but not exactly I want to test. I want to test not `css` content but `html` content loading.