# How does a mobile phone know to use a different page?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm making a website in Django, but i want to make two sites one for the phone and one for the computer.

How do you instruct phones to load my phone friendly page instead of the normal website?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a single Django project for many screens by using i.e. front-end responsive framework such like Bootstrap or Fundation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Django but I think you'll be able to accomplish this by adding this to your `<head>` section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
  if (screen.width <= 800) {
    window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
  }
  //-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to include the django mobile package. Much easier than trying to keep your own list of user agents to respond too. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mobile

Comment: I think it does not require a external package to do that simple thing. It's better to use @soerium solution

Comment: @DavidW. Front-end responsive frameworks like Bootstrap make sense for scaling content for layout, but if your content contains images you're stuck loading a full sized image and scaling it down (wasting bandwidth and increasing loading time), or depending on the <picture> tag which isn't well supported yet. Either way, most front end solutions will have a negative impact on SEO.

Comment: CSS Media Queries (in bootstrap) solve the problem since they prevent useless resources download in most recent browsers. (cf here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16668355/2255491)

Comment: @DavidW. You only use images for backgrounds? Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't serve a different site to the mobile device. Instead, you use CSS techniques (like [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)) to change the layout of the page based on the size of the browser.

This is called "responsive web design", (if that makes it a bit easier to search for) and has the advantage of not needing to maintain multiple copies of the same page, just to target different devices. Also, by applying rules based on the screen-size (rather than the device user agent), you can change the layout of your page when the user changes the size of the window - like by snapping windows side-by-side on desktop or switching from landscape to portrait on mobile. And, you can test your site at different sizes just by resizing the browser - no need to reload or even use the Chrome device emulator for the majority of your layout testing.

You can even use responsive web design without really understanding CSS, by using a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Answer (score -1):

By `User-Agent`, display size etc.
eg:

```
 if ($http_user_agent ~* '(blackberry|blazer|danger|ericsson|
        Google\s+Wireless\s+Transcoder|htc|iemobile|ipaq|iphone|ipod|lg|mobile|
        mot|moto|motorola|nec\-|netfront|netfront|nokia|opera\s+mini|palm|
        palmsource|panasonic|philips|pocketpc|samsung|sanyo|sec|sharp|sie\-|
        smartphone|sony|symbian|t\-mobile|untrusted|up\.browser|up\.link|
        vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|webOS|windows\s+ce)') {
      set $mobile on;
    }
```

Taken from [here](https://www.chicagodjango.com/blog/mobile-web-development-django/):