# Adding thumbnails to websites

Tags: javascript, html, perl, dancer

So I am learning how to make websites by building an image gallery.

And the images i am using are big, so realized that i can put in resized images for thumbnails and decided on 500px width images

These thumbnails look crisp on mobile, ok on tablet but blurred on desktop.
So I figured I need 500px for mobiles and tablets  but say 700px for desktop.

So this leaves me the problem of choosing between the two in runtime.

From what I understand I can do this two ways.

1. Check screen size from javascript generate html on the browser(client) using javascript (not sure how to do this yet).
2. Check User agent for string "Mobile" and decide on server.

Or is there some other way?
So which one of these two methods is better or has less drawbacks?

I would guess "2" is better since it works even when javascript is disabled
I am using Perl Dancer2 if it helps in any way

Comment: Is CSS an option? If so, I would suggest you look at media queries, as you can define a class that presents your image's width to be 500px if the browser width is < 800px, and a image width of 700px if the browser width is >= 800px (these widths are just an example).

Comment: This article has some helpful resources: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/

Comment: @Shoeless I am actually using that to resize the elements to fit screen right now. But how would it help in deciding which thumbnail to choose? as far as i understand if i give 500px in css it would still download the large file and scale it to 500px on screen

Comment: Ah, I see; I thought you were resizing the same image. If you want to load different images using CSS, I'd suggest looking at SRCSET.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use mediaqueries as is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657159/when-using-media-queries-does-a-phone-load-non-relevent-queries-and-images)

You can always write in the html the two sizes but with mediaqueries only one will be shown.

Other way is getting with javascript the height and width of the window, you will know what resolution has the client that is using the web, so you could append to the images _full, or _low to difference this cases.

I don't suggest you using the UserAgent, because there are old PC's that have less resolution that actual mobile devices, so I think is better to work with the dpi/resolution of the window.

You have some examples of mediaqueries [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: Media queries will not fulfill the requirement because the OP is not scaling the same image for different widths- the images are different files for different widths.

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that the image is not scaling, but being replaced, I suggest you utilize SRCSET, which will allow you to define different images based on pixel density and width. [SitePoint provides a good overview](https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-images-part-1-using-srcset/).

Here's a sample from their article:

```
<img src="low-density-photo.jpg" srcset="small-photo.jpg 480w, big-photo.jpg 1024w, high-density-photo.jpg 1024w 2x" />
```