# jQuery Image Swap Issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple swap img src when the browser is resized to a smaller screen but for some reason my code is not working. Hope someone can help with this issue. I have the 2d image in the same folder as the first one.

Thanks

HTML Code:

```
<div class="body-bg">
   <img src="img-01.jpg" class="img-01">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <h2>Example</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(function(){

    var $window = $(window);

function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 750) {
        $('.img-01').attr('src','img-01.jpg');
    }
    else if ($window.width() > 750) {
        $('.img-01').attr('src','img-02.jpg');
    }
}

});
```

Comment: "My code is not working" does not explain the issue. Please explain what's not working. Is it just not switching the images? Is it overlaying one on top of the other? Please go in more depth.

Comment: It's not switching the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually running the `resize` function. Try replacing your javascript with this:

```
$(function(){
    var $window = $(window);

    function resize() {
        if ($window.width() < 750) {
            $('.img-01').attr('src','img-01.jpg');
        }
        else if ($window.width() > 750) {
            $('.img-01').attr('src','img-02.jpg');
        }
    }

    $window.on('resize', resize);
});
```

`$window.on('resize', resize);` runs the function on the window resize event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the declared resize function in

1) document ready function and

2) on window resize event.

Also your code to select image can be optimized as shown below.

```
$(function(){

var $window = $(window);
var img_01= $('.img-01');
function resize() {
   img_01.attr('src',$window.width() < 750 ? 'img-01.jpg' :'img-02.jpg');
}
 resize();
 $window.on('resize', resize);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the .[resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)() jquery method

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var $window= $(this); //this = window 
    if ($window.width() < 750) {
        $('.img-01').attr('src','img-01.jpg');
    }else if ($window.width() > 750) {
        $('.img-01').attr('src','img-02.jpg');
    }
});
```

---

With pure js:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight < 750) {
        $('.img-01').attr('src','img-01.jpg');
    }
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1280) {
        $('.img-01').attr('src','img-02.jpg');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to listen for the resize event like this :

```
$(function() {   

  var $window = $(window);

  function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 750) {
      $('.img-01').attr('src', 'img-01.jpg');
    } else if ($resize()window.width() > 750) {
      $('.img-01').attr('src', 'img-02.jpg');
    }
  }

  resize();

  $window.on("resize", function() {
    resize();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using JavaScript, consider use CSS's @media for this? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16668355/4551487) mobile browsers should respect @media, and not to download unnecessary images anyway.

```
<style>
.mobile-only{display: none;}
.desktop-only{display: block;}

@media (min-width:750px) {
  .mobile-only{display: block;}
  .desktop-only{display: none;}
}
</style>


<div class="body-bg">
   <img src="img-01.jpg" class="img-01 mobile-view">
   <img src="img-01.jpg" class="img-01 desktop-view">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <h2>Example</h2>
</div>
```