# Is an background image applied via embedded CSS loaded on mobile if media query sets something else as background?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have an image applied as background-image to an element by embedded CSS:

```
<div style="background-image:url(image.jpg)"></div>
```

On mobile, I do away with that image:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

My question is: on mobile, although the background-image is no longer applied thanks to the media query, will the image still be loaded in memory and hence use bandwidth?

Comment: why not check the network tab of your browser (press f12), it will show you what is loaded.  Also to override an inline style, you would need to use `!important`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657159/when-using-media-queries-does-a-phone-load-non-relevent-queries-and-images

Comment: the image will not be loaded